Why do I get "Too many client tasks" accessing an MS Access database through MFC via ODBC despite closing my connections?
I have an MFC/C++ application which accesses an MS Access database via ODBC using MFC's CRecordset class (All very "last century", I know, but so is this app I'm trying to maintain so bear with me).
Recently, I've discovered that the code doing database inserts is throwing a CDBException "Too many client tasks". The exception seems to only happen once 63 inserts have been made to the database using CRecordset::AddNew(). After this happens, every database operation results in the same error for the life of the application. I say "recently" because I don't know when the problem started since it's only recently that people have started making enough additions to the DB to trigger the error.
Access has a hard coded limit of 64 connections per process but, as far as I can tell, I am closing each connection once its work is done. Everything is synchronous, single thread. Googling the error gives me almost exclusively MS Excel/VBA results of people simply not calling Close() on their connections in a loop.
I tried to enable ODBC tracing in the ODBC administrator but, incredibly, enabling ODBC tracing eliminates the problem! I can call Open() -> AddNew() -> Update() -> Close() literally hundreds of times with no issue except that tracing makes everything extremely slow and writes a few dozen MiB/s to the log file.
Here are the bones of the code being used:
CRecordset RS;
try
{
  RS.open(CRecordset::dynaset, SQLQuery);
  RS.AddNew()
  ...
//  <set values for RS>
  ...
  RS.Update();
  RS.Close();
}
catch(CDBException* ex)
{
  if(RS.IsOpen()
  {
    RS.Close();
  }
}

//<the same basic code then runs again for a different table/CRecordset but in the same database>

The connection string for the recordset is ODBC;DSN=MyDSN
The driver being used is for 64-bit Access Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)/ACEODBC.DLL. The version is either 16.00.5378 or 16.00.4513 (both behave the same).
This code is sometimes called once, sometimes dozens of times in a loop. But as long as it runs 63 times during the lifetime of the program, it will trigger the error. The exception is thrown by the Open() method of the recordset.
As I mentioned, I tried enabling ODBC tracing but the problem doesn't occur when tracing is enabled. I've tried adding a Sleep(1000) between some of the DB operations but it never made any difference.
Why am I getting the error "Too many client tasks" if I am (as I think) closing my DB connections and why does ODBC tracing eliminate the problem?

Found this, it is for VB language and Excel database though.

Another thing you could try is pass a CDatabase object to the CRecordset constructor, which you should have previously opened yourself. This way the operation will be using only one connection, and would be much faster too. You may also want to set auto-commit to off, so you can make the whole operation a single transaction - you will have to begin and commit/rollback the transaction yourself.

@ConstantineGeorgiou This is what I ended up doing. There were less code changes than I thought and, as a bonus, everything should be faster this way. Thanks for your suggestions.
